# Getting a Common Member on a Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Every entity class in my application must implement the following interface:

```
public interface IEntity<T> {
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Almost 100% of the time the type of T will be an int. However I have to deal with cases were the id may be a composite id. E.g. I could have the following implementations:

```
public class User : IEntity<int> {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Site : IEntity<int> {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class UserSite : IEntity<UserSiteIdentifier> {
    public UserSiteIdentifier Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

// Note: IIdentifier doesn't have any members
public class UserSiteIdentifier : IIdentifier {
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    ...

    public override ToString() {
        return User.Id + "|" + Site.Id;
    }
}
```

Now given an entity instance (where the type is unknown) I need to retrieve the id and convert it to a string. I could say:

```
object entity = ???;
string id;

if (entity is IEntity<int>)
    id = ((IEntity<int>)entity).Id.ToString();
else if (entity is IEntity<IIdentifier>)
    id = ((IEntity<IIdentifier>)entity).Id.ToString();
```

But this code doesn't sit right with me as I have to repeat almost the same code just to handle composite id's.

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me a cleaner solution. This application is still a prototype and is completely open to suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Why not just use entity.ToString()?

Comment: @looper thanks but I need to make sure the object implements IEntity<T> aswell.

Comment: Even though any `UserSiteIdentifier` is an `IIdentifier`, you can't conclude that an `IEntity<UserSiteIdentifier>` is also an `IEntity<IIdentifier>`. That would require your `IEntity<T>` interface to be **covariant (`out`) in `T`**. It can't be made `IEntity<out T>` because it also mentions a setter. The setter is like a method taking a `T` as in-parameter. What I'm trying to say is that I don't think your `else if` condition above will work.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen cheers I kinda guessed that line may throw an error I was just hoping it helped show my problem. Rafal's answer is working perfectly for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce `IEntity` interface:

```
public interface IEntity<T>:IEntity {
    new T Id { get; set; }
}

 public interface IEntity {
    object Id { get; }
}
```

There will be some inconvenience while implementing two properties which are supposed to return the same value but this can be overcome by introducing base class `Entity<T>` which will hide the `object Id` property.

```
public class Entity<T>:IEntity<T> {
    public T Id { get; set; }
    object IEntity.Id { get{ return Id;}  }
}
```

then your problematic code could be:

```
object value =...;
var entity = value as IEntity;
string id;
if(entity != null)
    id = entity.Id.ToString();
```